# HTML working in firefox and IE but not in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

Hi I have designed a website but unfortunately it is not working in chrome and perfectly fine in Firefox and IE. I am a beginner at HTML programming. Below is the code. Please do assist if possible.

The issue is a button that i have placed in the code is not being displayed in the required location in chrome.

```js
 $j(document).ready(function() {
   if (_jive_effective_user_id == -1) {
     // anonymous or not logged in user
     $j("#getStartedLink").attr("href", "link1");
     $j("#getStartedLink1").attr("href", "link2");
     $j("#getStartedLink2").attr("href", "/login.jspa?fromMP=3193&clickedOnDownload=sd");
     $j("#getStartedLink3").attr("href", "/login.jspa?fromMP=3193&clickedOnDownload=sd");
   } else {
     // logged in user
     $j("#getStartedLink").attr("href", "link3");
     $j("#getStartedLink1").attr("href", "link4");
     $j("#getStartedLink2").attr("href", "link5");
     $j("#getStartedLink3").attr("href", "link6");
   }
 });
```

```css
.contents {
  <!--margin: auto auto auto -22px;
  --> width: 103.6%;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000;
}
.shadow {
  padding-top: 0;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000;
  min-height: 340px;
}
body {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'FuturaStd-Light';
  line-height: 1.231;
}
#jive-body-main {
  width: 100%;
}
#jive-widget-content {
  padding: 0 0px;
}
#footer .footer-tab-contents .contents {
  background: transparent;
}
.gradient2 {
  display: none;
}
.gradient {
  display: block;
}
.webcast_list li {
  list-style-image: none;
}
.container_12 .grid_7 {
  width: 90%;
}
.tab-inner-devPortal p {
  font-family: 'FuturaStd-Light';
}
.jive-widget-body .jive-html-text-widget ul li {
  list-style-type: disc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-inner" style="background-color: white; margin-bottom: 1px; border-bottom:1px solid rgb(210,210,210);">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="container_12">
      <div class="grid_6 text-center" style="margin-top:103px;">
        <img src="IMAGE" alt="" style="width:450px; margin-top: -78px;">
      </div>
      <div class="grid_6 box suffix_05" style="padding-right:0px;">
        <p class="" style="font-size:150%; margin-top:-50px;"><strong style="margin-left: -350px;">TEXT</strong>
        </p>
        <p class="lh190" style="font-size:15px;">The <a href="link" target="_new">Text:</a>
      </div>
      <div style="float: left">
        <ul class="webcast_list" style="margin-top: -135px; font-size:15px; margin-left: 510px; list-style-image: none;">
          <li style="margin-bottom: 8px;">Text</li>
          <li style="margin-bottom: 8px;">Text</li>
          <li style="margin-bottom: 8px;">Text</li>
          <li style="margin-bottom: 8px;">Text</li>
          <li style="margin-bottom: 8px;">Text</li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
      <a href="HTML form" class="btn-more" style="margin-bottom: -3px; margin-left: -35px; margin-top: 85px; text-transform:none;">Button</a>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why you are using `$j`?

Comment: which button are you talking about ?

Comment: @Sanjeev I have altered the text to show you what button it is. I know its not a Javascript issue. Its something to do with the CSS

Comment: You have syntax error in your css. The comment should be `/* your:property;` */ May be that is why it is breaking in chrome

Comment: @AdityaParab : Can you be more specific

Comment: He means that you should have /* margin: auto auto auto -22px;
*/ instead of <!--margin: auto auto auto -22px;  -->

Answer (score 0):

Please write clean code. I can't understand what did you want to do!
You have 4 solution:

1. Margins don't work properly on inline level elements. The `<a>` element is an inline element. You should change the display property of `<a>` to block.

   `<a href="HTML form" style="display: block; margin-bottom: -3px; margin-left: -35px; margin-top: 85px; text-transform:none;">Button</a>`
2. Relative positioning
3. Absolute positioning
4. You can style the first parent div element of a.